# How to execute an Akka Streams Source?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a `Source` like this:

```
val colorSource = myMethod(ctx, id)
  .via(framing("\n"))
  .map(_.utf8String)
  .map(_.trim)
  .map(c => ColorParser(c))
  .collect {
    case Right(color) => color
  }
```

How can I actually run this and get `List[Color]`? For starters, I would like to print it to view the contents, and then also be able to pass around the `List[Color]` to other methods.

I did this to print it, but it didn't work:

```
val values = for {
  t <- colorSource.runWith(Sink.ignore)
} yield t
total.map(println _)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain a `Future[List[Color]]`:

```
val colorList: Future[List[Color]] =
  colorSource
    .runWith(Sink.seq[Color])
    .map(_.toList)
```

If you want to just print the contents of the stream:

```
colorSource.runForeach(println)
```

Comment: How about passing values from it around to another method?

Comment: Sink.foreach(println) doesn't work. returns `expected Procedure[NotInferedT], actual: Unit`